# How do I return the correct ID based on a different known attribute in this JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm new to JSON, how can I get the `variation_id` from this JSON based on the `attributes_pa_trainer`. jQuery and/or vanilla js answers are both appreciated.

Here's the JSON.

```
[{
    "variation_id": "2446",
    "attributes": {
        "attribute_pa_trainer": "angus"
    },
    "image_src": "",
    "image_link": "",
    "image_title": "",
    "image_alt": "",
    "price_html": "",
    "availability_html": "",
    "sku": "TEST-ANGUS",
    "weight": " kg",
    "dimensions": "",
    "min_qty": 1,
    "max_qty": 0,
    "backorders_allowed": false,
    "is_in_stock": true,
    "is_downloadable": false,
    "is_virtual": true,
    "is_sold_individually": "no"
}, {
    "variation_id": "2447",
    "attributes": {
        "attribute_pa_trainer": "anthony"
    },
    "image_src": "",
    "image_link": "",
    "image_title": "",
    "image_alt": "",
    "price_html": "",
    "availability_html": "",
    "sku": "TEST-ANTHONY",
    "weight": " kg",
    "dimensions": "",
    "min_qty": 1,
    "max_qty": 0,
    "backorders_allowed": false,
    "is_in_stock": true,
    "is_downloadable": false,
    "is_virtual": true,
    "is_sold_individually": "no"
}]
```

I'm looking for a solution to complete a function like the below

```
// On button click
$('.purchase_btn').click(function() {
    // Set trainer to the value of the button's data attribute
    var trainer = $(this).data('trainer');
    // variations_json is the full json
    var variations_json = $('.variations_form').data('product_variations');
    // Get the variation id based on the trainer
    var variation_id = [some way of getting the variation ID from the above json];
    // Set a hidden field to the variation id
    $('#variation_id').val(variation_id);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`grep` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to filter the objects. Assuming that you find one, the result is an array with one item, so you get the variation id from that item:

```
var variation_id = $.grep(variations_json, function(o){
  return o.attributes.attribute_pa_trainer == trainer;
})[0].variation_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

so [{id:1, name:"test"}, {id:2, name:"test2"}] is an array of json objects. So, I am little bit confused with your question, are you trying to get variation_id from each json object in the array ? or you want to do a loop through the array and find one of the json object and get its variation_id ?

Guffa's solution would work, but you just need to be careful with the jquery function, if nothing found, then it will return an empty array, so if the array is empty, array[0] will return an error.

Comment: JSON can be either an array or an object. http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to just loop through the JSON with jQuery's each function. I assume grep does more or less the same internally. This would look somewhat like this:

```
$.each(variations_json, function() {
    if(this.attributes.attribute_pa_trainer == trainer){
    variation_id =this.variation_id;
}
});
```

The downside being, that the whole JSON will be traversed no matter what, i.e. it obviously doesn't break off, when the trainer is found.